# Java can't use public method from one package in the another

Tags: java, package, static-methods, public-method

In the same project I have two packages, 1st package contains a class with this code:

```
package com.ginger;

public class SimplePrint 
{   

    public SimplePrint(){}

    public static void print(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }   
}
```

I would like use the method `print()` in another class in another package, but within the same project.

```
import com.ginger.*;

public class MainClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        print("Some");
    }
}
```

But the compiler tells me that the method `print()` is undefined for the 2nd class.

In the same time, I am able to create the object `SimplePrint s = new SimplePrint()` in the 2nd class.

I'm new to the programming, excuse me if i am asking about the simple thing.

Comment: Did you import your first package into your class? `import yourpackagename.theclassinpackagename;` or `import yourpackagename.*;`.

Comment: Dude! You really need to learn java. First of all, you needn't use static for the method print. If you need to access any method of SimplePrint class you need to create an object of that class so that you could access the instance variables and methods of that class. Here it would be SimplePrint SimplePrint1 = new SimplePrint(); SimplePrint.print();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

### Non-static

Remove the `static` keyword of the method `print` and create an instance of the class

```
SimplePrint simplePrint = new SimplePrint();
```

and just do this

```
simplePrint.print("");
```

Or combine the above into a single line:

```
new SimplePrint().print("");
```

### Static

You keep the `print` method `static` and just do this

```
SimplePrint.print("");
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I have just misunderstood how static works.

Comment: Note that you can also use a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html), e.g. `import static com.ginger.SimplePrint.print;`. This way the original `print("Some");` statement would also work.

Comment: EricBouwers - now I got it!!! Oh, thank you! It was my error, I forgot about import **static**. It's what I was intended to do.

Comment: If `SimplePrint.print("")` still doesn't work, make sure you're doing this in a method scope. Hope this saves time to others.

Answer (score 0):

static keyword for a method implies its a class level.

If  keyword like static is not used for a method it means instance level,so create instance and then access it.